# Loading self signed https url in an iFrame,Chrome is not asking for add excp

Tags: javascript, iframe

When I am loading a https (self signed ssl) url in a tab, chrome is showing a message "
Your connection is not private" and providing an option to proceed "Proceed to  (unsafe)".

[image]

But when I am loading the same URL inside as an iframe (Parent window also https)..Same option is not available to add exception.. and I am getting net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE error in console

How to resolve this..

[image]

I want the same options to be displayed inside iframe.

Please let me know if any have idea about this.
Thanks in advance..